# how to get API response it in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, httprequest

i have the following API json request

```
 "myjsonrequest": {
                        "ServiceKey": "Hello",
                        "Identityvals": {
                                        "IDName": "regnum",
                                        "IDValue": "112233"
                        }
        }
```

any simple way to get the response , im using ASP.net c#

i tried this code

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string x = "{'IDName','regnum'},{'IDValue','112233'}";
            var Keys = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                   { "ServiceKey", "hello" },
                   { "PractitionerIdentity",x}
                };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(Keys);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://apiurl", content);
        var responseval = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: can you share the error message ?

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? is it throwing an exception? not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var json = new {
          ServiceKey = "",
          PractitionerIdentity = new {
              IDName = "" ,
              IDValue = ""            
           }  
         };
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://apiurl", content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json data should be saved to a model in the following way:

```
    public class YourJsonData{
        public string ServiceKey {get; set;}
        //add other names
    }
```

The best thing about this is that if you call your object, you get a variable back for easy usage.

then you can add it in a task:

```
    public async Task<List<YourJsonData>> GetJsonAsync(CancellationToken  cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Make the request, and ensure we can reach it
            var response = await client.GetAsync(yourJosnUrl, cancellationToken);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Read the actual stream (download the content)
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                //Make sure we do have some valid content before we try to deserialize it
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
                {
                    return new List<YourJsonData>();
                }

                //Deserialize into a list of yourjsondata
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourJsonData>>(content);
            }
        }
        return new List<YourJsonData>();
    }
```

also if you are lazy, you can replace YourJsonData with dynamic. the downpart here is that you won't be able to see what you are revering to.